# Starting Pig gives an Error Name node is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop/PIG.
After restarting my machine and then started my VMs to run PIG, it is giving me  the following error when i try to run:

```
grunt> A = load '1.txt';    
grunt> dump A;
```

> ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer -
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot
>   delete /tmp/temp-1824625143. Name node is in safe mode. The ratio of
>   reported blocks 0.6964 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode
>   will be turned off automatically.

Comment: I used hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave and it worked.
However I wanted to know the reason as to why it went into that mode after a restart?

Comment: How many datanodes do you have in your VM cluster?

Comment: So when you started up your VMs again, did both VMs come up, and both datanodes on each VM? Check the logs for both the datanodes

Comment: There are no errors on the data nodes of both the VMs.

Comment: It is happening every time i restart dfs and mapred. i.e., every time I run start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh

Comment: After a while, does the NameNode report 1.0 for reported blocks? I.e. is this just a problem when hadoop initially starts and it takes a while for the datanodes to scan their blocks and report in with the name node?

Comment: This is what the namenode says:    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:nikhil cause:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
2012-06-14 12:15:29,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 9000, call delete(/var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system, true) from 10.232.0.77:42802: error:

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.

Comment: sounds like you have permission problems - did you start the task trackers as root or another user?

Comment: what does `ls -l /var/tmp/hadoop/mapred/system` show as it's result (and the directories above it)

Comment: mapred has only "local" as its directory. It does not show "system".

Comment: Does the user under which you run HDFS services have permissions to create the system folder in mapred?

Comment: Yes I do have permissions. Do you feel it can be permission issue? Should I try to change /var/tmp/hadoop directory to some other directory?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have run out of memory blocks in order to run your program. These blocks will be deleted automatically when space runs out once you exit safemode. To exit safemode in hadoop use the command:

---

`hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`